# How to add DATE_ADD(CREATION_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY) in yii2 select query

Tags: mysql, yii2

How to add DATE_ADD(CREATION_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY)  in yii2 select query

select DATE_ADD(CREATION_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY) from tablename

you can found several useful info in this guide

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

Comment: You may want to give some more information, provide code and sample data. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is select literal in select (and in general in you query function)

```
$query->select('DATE_ADD(CREATION_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY) ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property that add 5 days to CREATION_DATE in the model:

```
public function getCreationDatePostFiveDays
{
     $date = new DateTime($this->CREATION_DATE);
     $date->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
     return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

usable with:

```
$model->creationDatePostFiveDays;
```